# How to isolate group from computers by L3 switch from certain www

Tags: switch, vlan, qos

There is a broken switch to replace and I need to buy new one. I decide on this model: 
https://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-LGS528/
 Is it possible to isolate 24 computers that are connected to this switch from certain www adresses (games, youtube, porn etc) and leave 2 ports untouched at this switch? Are there any other model or solution to do this?

Answer (score 1):

what you want is most probably a filtering proxy that is enforced on the web-browsers.

Either this enforcement can be added at the router to send all requests to port 80/443 to the proxy or at DNS resolver level, to filter DNS requests for such domains.
The DNS variant does not require tampering with SSL certificates and setting up your own CA - so might be preferable.

A switch does have aspects of a router, but it does not replace the router in its sense of "access point to the internet".

Answer (score 0):

It is not the task of a switch to filter network packets, especially not on so vaguely defined criteria.

The switch can separate the computers into two (or more) different VLANs, and a router can provide different access rules for the different VLANs.

Comment: "The hardware inside a Layer 3 switch blends that of traditional switches and routers". Isn't that a better to cut unwanted traffic closer the source to make whole network work faster?